# Can I get parental leave if my family is outside of Germany?

Tags: family

I have been working in Germany for the last 5 months. My wife is living in the USA. We are expecting a baby in two months. So:

1. Can I get paid parental leave? Unpaid?
2. If yes, for how long could I receive this benefit?

Answer (score 5):

No, the preconditions are ([§ 1 Absatz 1 BEEG](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/beeg/__1.html)):

- your main place of residence is in Germany
- you live in that household with the child

It is not paid leave, but you will eligible for **Elterngeld** (parent money).

- € 300 (minimum) ; € 1.800 (maximum)
- **or** 67% of your average earning of the previous 12 months

Between the birth and 3rd year of the child: 12 months

- the time can be split

The application must be made to your employer

- see [sample letter (as .doc or .pdf)](https://www.arbeitsrechte.de/elternzeit-vater)

If your wife, with child, move to Germany before the child is 3, then you would be eligible for the time up to the end if the third year.

---

**Sources**:

- [Recht auf Elternzeit als Vater - Arbeitsrecht 2020](https://www.arbeitsrechte.de/elternzeit-vater)

  - [§ 1 Absatz 1 BEEG](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/beeg/__1.html)
  - [§ 2 Absatz 1 - Höhe des Elterngeldes BEEG](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/beeg/__2.html)